# How to get access to long_description in setup after installation using pip?

Tags: python, setuptools

In the Python packaging [sampleproject](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject) there is a long description for the module, given in `setup.py` using:

```
# Get the long description from the README file
with open(path.join(here, 'README.rst'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
    long_description = f.read()
...
setup(
...
    # This is an optional longer description of your project that represents
    # the body of text which users will see when they visit PyPI.
    #
    # Often, this is the same as your README, so you can just read it in from
    # that file directly (as we have already done above)
    #
    # This field corresponds to the "Description" metadata field:
    # https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata/#description-optional
    long_description=long_description,  # Optional
```

How can the user get access to this descprtion, maybe in different format, after the module is installed with `pip install sampleproject`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import email
from pkg_resources import get_distribution

pkgInfo = get_distribution(package_name).get_metadata('PKG-INFO')
print(email.message_from_string(pkgInfo)['Description'])
```

`package_name` must be your distribution name. `pkgInfo` is a string that contains all metadata for the package, so I use `email` to parse it and return `Description` as a header. A little dirty trick.

Comment: Thanks; works nicely with the Python script.  However, my thought was how the user can get access to the information, like some `man` page or through an ´--help´ option, since I assume the intention with the "long_description" is to provide documentation to the user.

Comment: I don't know a command-line tool for that. `pip show` doesn't show `long_description`.

Comment: Long description is probably only provided in [Project Description](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#description) on PyPI, as described in [Packaging and Distributing Projects :: Description](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#description).

Comment: For me (python 3.8), the long description is in the "METADATA" file. Parsing is just everything after the header (the header is terminated by "\n\n"): `get_distribution("abstractcp").get_metadata("METADATA").split("\n\n", 1)[1]`. @EquipDev obviously you could provide a small executable in your own package that retrieves this and shows it as a help file, but indeed pip doesn't seem to provide this.